# I am getting a "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:" Error on VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When I type a basic hello world code in C language an error pops up,

[image]

The code I wrote was,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf( "Welcome to C!\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't post images of text

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Would you mind to add the command line(s) that you use to compile and link, please, after you copied the shell output verbatim? Yes, you can do this in any shell, even on Windows. ;-)